# How to remove duplicates, by sublist item subset, in a list of lists in Python?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists in Python that is defined like this: `[[2, 3, 5], [3, 3, 1], [2, 3, 8]]`, not I want to delete the duplicate entries, but by duplicate I mean that the first two elements of each list match, for example, the first and third list have 2 and 3 as their first and second elements, therefore, I count it as a duplicate, and after removing I want to have the final list: `[[2, 3, 5], [3, 3, 1]]`. Currently, I have something like this:

```
arr = [[2, 3, 5], [3, 3, 1], [2, 3, 8]]

first = [item[0] for item in arr]
second = [item[1] for item in arr]
zipped = zip(first, second)
```

This produces list of tuples with the first two entries of each list. Now, I can try to get the index of duplicate entries and remove those indices from the original list. But, are there shorter ways to do what I want? If not, what is the best way to get the duplicate indices here?

Comment: Does it matter if the first or last of the duplicate entries gets discarded?

Comment: @vikvanderlinden Nope, but I would prefer to keep the first one, though, not a big deal in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

You can use sets to accomplish this:

```
arr = [[2, 3, 5], [3, 3, 1], [2, 3, 8]]

used = set()
[used.add(tuple(x[:2])) or x for x in arr if tuple(x[:2]) not in used]
```

returns

```
[[2, 3, 5], [3, 3, 1]]
```

### Notes

1. The first expression is only evaluated if the first two elements of any sublist are not in `used`. Checkout [the docs on list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for more info.
2. Know that `set.add` always returns `None`. So `used.add(tuple(x[:2])) or x` always evaluates to `x`.
3. We need to convert the first two elements of a sublist to an immutable (e.g. tuple) since `list` is not hashable.

Finally as @wim brings up if you're not familiar with this pattern it can be difficult to understand and in Python "Readability counts." So if you're writing code that will be shared consider changing this to an explicit `for` loop or using another approach.

Comment: Abusing the return value of `set.add` and short-circuiting the `or` is a bit too subtle.  Just use a plain old for loop and append, if you want to do it like this.

Comment: @wim to each his/her own... I use this pattern pretty frequently now so it's second nature.

Comment: Using list comprehension side-effects can be second nature to you, sure, but may be unreadable to others.  The awkwardness of the one-liner approach also required to slice the prefix from each element *twice*, when it should only be needed once.

Comment: @wim making a note of this in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.OrderedDict` for an order-preserving de-dupe:

```
>>> d = OrderedDict(((x[0], x[1]), x) for x in reversed(L))
>>> print(*d.values())
[2, 3, 5] [3, 3, 1]
```

To keep the last instead of the first, just remove the `reversed`:

```
>>> OrderedDict(((x[0], x[1]), x) for x in L).values()
odict_values([[2, 3, 8], [3, 3, 1]])
```

Or use a plain old for-loop:

```
def dedupe(iterable):
    seen = set()
    for x in iterable:
        first, second, *rest = x
        if (first, second) not in seen:
            seen.add((first, second))
            yield x
```